# Emmet interference in snippet with curly braces

Tags: html, sublimetext3, liquid, emmet

Have some problem with expanding function with Emmet, like in this [Gif Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmm9Z.gif). My attempts to edit Emmet's settings file with "ignore_scope" weren't successful. When I try to fill snippet with some variables and code by pressing "Tab", Emmet removes braces. I think there is a method that prevent Emmet from expanding inside some braces scope (maybe only in .liquid files).

Comment: Can you post the snippet(s) you’re using?

Comment: <snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
{% if ${1:condition} %}
 ${2:what to do}
{% endif %}
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>if</tabTrigger>
<description>liquid if</description>
<scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>